# Comparar fecha actual con fecha final Oracle Java Current_date

Tags: java, sql, oracle, select, date

Al tratar de comparar fechas en java con bdd oracle usando `current_date`, tengo un problema con el campo `UZGTFORMULARIOS_FECHA_FIN` es `TIPO VARCHAR`. Y se guarda en formato **21/12/2019** al usar el `to_date()` me sale el error:

> java.sql.SQLDataException: ORA-01843: mes no válido

y al usar el `to_char` me aparecen registros, pero no los correctos

Select que uso en el sqldeveloper

```
select * from UTIC.UZGTFORMULARIO_PERSONA p,UTIC.UZGTFORMULARIOS f where
p.spriden_pidm ='2401 'and p.codigo_uzgtformularios = f.codigo_uzgtformularios
and ( p.uzgtformularios_estado_llenado ='N') AND UZGTFORMULARIOS_FECHA_FIN >= (current_Date)


LinkedList<Integer> codForms = new LinkedList<Integer>();
try{
    ResultSet resu = co.prepareStatement("select p.codigo_uzgtformularios from 
    UTIC.UZGTFORMULARIO_PERSONA p,UTIC.UZGTFORMULARIOS f where p.spriden_pidm =" + 
    PIDMget + "and p.codigo_uzgtformularios = f.codigo_uzgtformularios and 
    (p.uzgtformularios_estado_llenado ='N') AND UZGTFORMULARIOS_FECHA_FIN >=
    to_DATE(current_Date, 'DD/MM/RRRR')").executeQuery();

    while (resu.next()) {
        Integer codForm = resu.getInt(1);
        codForms.add(codForm);
    }
    resu.close();
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    out.println("error select " + ex);
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bienvenido a StackOverflow

Yo suelo usar sysdate en lugar de current_date, si UZGTFORMULARIOS_FECHA_FIN ya es un varchar simplemente parseo la fecha actual a varchar

```
 UZGTFORMULARIOS_FECHA_FIN >= to_char(sysdate,'DD-MM-YYYY')
```

Comment: muchas gracias, problema solucionado